# Searching for movie dataset containing movie synopses?

Tags: recommender-system

To build a hybrid recommendation system, I used the movielens 1M dataset, for the collaborative filtering part. Now, I'm looking for a database/dataset that contains descriptions/summaries/details/synopses/plots of movies for the content-based recommendation.
Is there someone who could help me and tell me where I can find a such dataset?
thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is better suited for https://opendata.stackexchange.com/